# 4 divs, last row double stacked inside another div

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to accomplish is this
[image]

I am working on it currently and just cant get it right, I started 2 jsfiddles trying to do this but nothing is working.

verison 1: http://jsfiddle.net/ewa0nLjk/1/

```
.tutlist {
    width:500px;
    height:75px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    margin: 40px;
    /*margin not required*/
}
.tutlist div {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.left {
    width: 75px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    display: inline;
}
.middle {
    width: 500px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline;
}
.right {
    width: 120px;
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    display: inline;
}

    <div class="tutlist">     
        <div class="left">
         <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3726/13855354235_887ae071c0_s.jpg"/></div>     
        <div class="middle">how to send an email in php code testing it</div>     
        <div class="right">double</div> 
    </div>
```

version 2: http://jsfiddle.net/R65fA/1/

```
#header {

    padding:5px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    margin: 30px;
    width:500px;
    /*margin not required*/
}
.header-left {
    width:75px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background:red;

}
.logo {
    width:409px;
    display:inline;
    background:red;


}
.header-right {
    width:75px;
    background:red;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
}

#clear {
        clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
<div id="header">
        <div class="header-left">
            <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3726/13855354235_887ae071c0_s.jpg"/>
    </div>
        <div class="logo">
            how to send an email in php code testing it
    </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            RIGHT
    </div>
    <div id="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

Pretty much I have 3 divs, and the last div has 2 smaller divs in it. I am having trouble with this if someone can assist me would be awesome.

EDIT: One quick issue with setting up width auto.

how do I set the blue to fill up the remaining width of the while maininfo div? This is my jsfiddle.net/4ykf5frk/2, I tried setting the width:auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this updated example based on your first code:

```css
.tutlist {
  width: 500px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 40px;
  /*margin not required*/
}
.tutlist div {} .left {
  width: 75px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline;
}
.middle {
  width: 290px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.right {
  width: 120px;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.right_top {
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.right_bottom {
  height: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tutlist">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3726/13855354235_887ae071c0_s.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="middle">how to send an email in php code testing it</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right_top">test</div>
    <div class="right_bottom">double
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have to use [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) for setting the rounded corners.

Hope this helps

Comment: {
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;  
} will change the borders

Comment: just updated my page to see you'd just done it! +1 for the snippet anyway! :)

Comment: I saw the snippet, and went 'its what the OP wanted,but....' wrote the border bit, sent and then saw you updated your post. Oh well, least OP now can see this does it :)

Comment: @MrCoder hehe, I see :)

Comment: @BrianCherdak exellent!

Comment: @emmanuel, how do I set the blue to fill up the remaining width of the while maininfo div? This is my http://jsfiddle.net/4ykf5frk/2/, I tried setting the **width:auto**

Comment: Please try: http://jsfiddle.net/4ykf5frk/3/. .smallblock width was 20% so I converted it's margin to percentage and used the remaining width for the .large (60%).

Comment: @emmanuel is there any way to not set the .large to a certain percentage and to just let it fill in automatically

Comment: You could use [width: calc(100% - 200px);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) but is not suggested as it has some cross browser issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/22YBU/735

```css
* {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.middle {
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
    <div class=right>
        <div class="right1">right1 inside</div>
        <div class="right2">right2 inside</div>
    </div>
    <div class=left>
        <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3726/13855354235_887ae071c0_s.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class=middle>
        Put text here Put text herePut text herevPut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text herePut text here Put text herePut text herevPut text herePut text herePut text herePut text here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, another user solved it, but I will still upvote!

Comment: You have to choose the solution that you like most. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier, set 3 divs in a row. And then, inside the third one, you set those smaller two divs.

Just a TIP: To make the inline divs same height, set them as `display:table-cell`. Plus, you'll be able to set vertical alignment...

```css
.left, .middle, .right {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.right-top, .right-bottom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='left'>
    content 1
</div>

<div class='middle'>
    content 2
</div>

<div class='right'>
    <div class='right-top'>
        content 3
    </div>
    <div class='right-bottom'>
        content 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, another user solved it, but I will still upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R65fA/30/).

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:100%;
}
.left {
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}
.middle {
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
}
.right {
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}

.right1{
   height:50px;   
    background-color: green;
}
.right2{
   height:50px;   
    background-color: purple;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="right1"></div>
        <div class="right2"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, another user solved it, but I will still upvote!